# # of solutions to linear congruences

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

in every proof I've seen that the equation
$$ax\equiv b\pmod{m}$$
has $\gcd(a, m$) solutions if $\gcd(a,m)\mid b$, the author shows that there exists one solution $r$,  assumes there exists another solution $s$ and then shows that, for any $t\in \{0,1,\dots, m-1\}$, $s+t\cdot\frac{m}{\gcd(a,m)}$ is another solution.

What I'm having problems with is the assumption that there exists another solution $s$, don't we need to prove that as well ?

Comment: This kind of proof is similar to induction. If you find one solution, the proof shows that there are infinitely many solutions. So you just need to find one simple solution.

Comment: I see now! Thanks!

Comment: @MattiP.  Do these type of proofs have a name?

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with $ax \equiv b \bmod m$.

Let $g=\gcd{(a,m)}$. Lets suppose that $g \mid b$. 
Then $\dfrac ag x \equiv \dfrac bg \, \bmod{\dfrac mg}$.

Note that $\bigg(\dfrac ag \bigg)^{-1}$ exists because 
     $\operatorname{gcd}\bigg(\dfrac ag, \dfrac mg \bigg)=1$.

Then $x \equiv \dfrac bg\bigg(\dfrac ag \bigg)^{-1} 
  \operatorname{mod}\bigg(\dfrac mg \bigg)$

Let $s$ be the unique integer such that $0 \le s \lt \dfrac mg$ and
$s \equiv \dfrac bg\bigg(\dfrac ag \bigg)^{-1} 
  \operatorname{mod}\bigg(\dfrac mg \bigg)$

Then we have
$x \equiv s \operatorname{mod}\bigg(\dfrac mg \bigg)$, which is equivalent to 
$x = s +  t\bigg(\dfrac mg \bigg)$.

If we desire $0 \le s \lt m$, then we need to require $t = 0,1,\dots,g-1$, not, as you said, $m-1$.